# Matlab + Arduino, fwrite error

Tags: matlab, serial-port, arduino

I'm using Arduino in Matlab. The task is controlling a servo motor.

The code works well at first try but **error occurs after several iterations.**

```
a=arduino('COM5');
a.servoAttach(1); 
for i = 1 : 10
  a.servoWrite(1,45);
end
```

The error turns out to be at `fwrite(s, [96 30], 'uint8');` in `arduino.m`. So I'm wondering if it's a problem on COM buffering.

I tried typing these lines in command line and waited for several seconds between consecutive `servoWrite()` but the problem is still there.

Comment: I cannot find any information about servoAttach online, but it seems to me a command to configure something. Maybe you should do that only once before the loop, and not on every iteration?

Comment: Thanks for that. At first I left the `servoAttach()` out of the loop. However After assuming it to be a COM buffer problem, I tried to attach and detach it every time. No luck with that. So let's go back to the very beginning. I updated my question. @BasSwinckels

Comment: What is the full text of the error you get? Is it always after the same number of iterations?

Comment: Not the same number. The error message is `error at fwrite(s, [96 30], 'uint8');` @nkjt

Comment: That's the *entire* error message?

Comment: It's not exactly the same words but no detailed information provided on this 'fwrite error'. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Use `dbstop if error` and check what the serial object is doing.